# tcphdr field name change between OS/X and Linux

Tags: c, linux, tcp, bsd

I've developed some network code on OS/X, and I'm getting bit by the renamed fields in struct tcphdr.  I'm getting a bunch of errors of the form: `"dpkt.c:597:36: error: ‘struct tcphdr’ has no member named ‘th_sport’ "`.  I've tried `#define __FAVOR_BSD 1` and `#define _BSD_SOURCE 1`, without success.

The command line is:

```
$ g++ -o dpkt -g  dpkt.c -lpcap
```

No change when I try

```
$ g++ -o dpkt -g  -D_BSD_SOURCE=1 dpkt.c -lpcap
```

Thanks...

Comment: In which order did you try the defines? and also, you don't need to #define them to 1, you can just do `#define _BSD_SOURCE`

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, order of defines matters. Not sure whether you are aware of that or not, but try adding

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#define __FAVOR_BSD
```

In that particular order somewhere in the beginning of your file.